# Can the "Bisector" be represented by a holomorphic function?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, plane-geometry

## Note:

In this  question, a  complex number is  counted as a  vector  initiated from the origin.

______________________________________________________________-

> Is there a holomorphic function $B:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ such that for every two non zero complex numbers $z,w$ with $z/w \notin \mathbb{R},$ the vector $B(z,w)$ is a non zero vector indicating to the  direction of the bisector of the angle $\angle (z,w) $?

## Motivation:

The  initial formula for the  "Bisector" of $\angle (z,w) $ is  $B'(z,w)=|z|w+|w|z$. But it is not  a  holomorphic function.(It is not even smooth at $z=0$  or  $w=0$). So we  search  for a holomorphic remedy, a  holomorphic  function  $B$ defined  on whole $\mathbb{C}^2$  such that $B(z,w)$ is real proportional to  $(|z|w+|w|z)$ via  a  non constant real function $\lambda$.

What about if  we require that such  $\lambda $ be  positive(Non negative)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a better answer than the other answer I gave, which is currently accepted. It also answers some of your questions in the comments on that answer. Pick a branch of log, then $B$ and $ (zw)^{1/2}$ are holomorphic and their arguments differ by a multiple of $\pi$ wherever they are both defined. So their quotient is a real holomorphic function and hence a real constant wherever it is defined. So locally, $B$ has to be a real multiple of some branch of $ (zw)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Note that answers aren't threaded, and that even their physical position may change (so "better than the previous answer", which some people try, doesn't work either).  To avoid appearing (as it did to me originally) like you are favourably comparing your own answer to someone else's, you may want to point out that you are saying this is "a better answer" than your *own* answer (currently accepted), at https://mathoverflow.net/a/292636/2383 .

Comment: Ah, I had not thought about how that phrase read, thanks.

Comment: "Previous" - would people on MO read that as about spatial position of answers? I would read it as about time of posting. But maybe that is too ambiguous because of editing?

Comment: @LSpice  I changed the accepted answer. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $w=1$ for simplicity. If the imaginary part $\Im z> 0$ then $\Im B(z,1)>0$ and if $\Im z< 0$ then $\Im B(z,1)<0$, so $B(z,1)$ vanishes on the line $\Im z=0$ so it is uniformly 0. The same thing happens for any $w$, just replace $\Im z$ by $\Im (z/w)$.

Comment: Ah, this only works if $\lambda $ is positive, i did not see that part of the question.

Comment: OK, restrict $z$ to a small disc where $\lambda$ has a fixed sign, without loss of generality it is positive, then apply the argument I gave.

Comment: Thank you for  your  very  interesting answer. Your answer  works for the  general case, with a few  modification. Very great answer. But  what about the following:  We require  B to be  defined on all $(z,w)$  with $z/w \notin \mathbb{R}$, a reasonable restriction since we need to have  an angle? In this case is there  a  holomorphic  bisector?

Comment: I was writing my previous comment and I was not realize of  your  previous  comment. As you said your answer is perfect.

Comment: Sure, just pick a branch of the logarithm and let $B=(zw)^{1/2}$.

Comment: But the  bisector  of  $(z, \bar z)$  or  $(z, -\bar z)$ can not  be  drown holomorphically.

Comment: Not that  we  exclude $z/w \in \mathbb{R}$  not $zw \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: One another motivation for this question: What is the explicit formula for the map $P(z,w.t)=$ the intersection point of 3 bisectors of triangle with vertex $z,w.t$ which is  defined on all triple $(z,w,t)$ which are in general position? Is it holomorphic?

Comment: @AliTaghavi If I remember my high school geometry correctly, the intersection point is $\frac{|z-w|t+|z-t|w+|w-t|z}{|z-w|+|z-t|+|w-t|}$.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko  Thank you for this  formula. What is the physical interpretation for this  point?(Motivated by the concept of centroid, the intersection point of  medians)?

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko  BTW do you remember the same formula for intersection point of altitude?Moreover do you think that the B in [this answer]( https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292631/can-the-bisector-be-represented-by-a-holomorphic-function/292640#292640)can be defined globally, on the  space of all triples of points which are in the in general position

Comment: @AliTaghavi the bisector of an angle in a triangle divides the opposite side proportionally to the sides enclosing the angle, and that immediately implies the formula I stated. Similarly, for the altitudes, the intersection point is $\frac{\tan(A)z+\tan(B)w+\tan(C)t}{\tan(A)+\tan(B)+\tan(C)}$, where $A$, $B$, $C$ are angles at the vertices $z$, $w$, $t$ respectively. But expressing those $\tan$ functions in terms of $z$, $w$, $t$ is less pleasant. I don't see why one could possibly expect these functions to be holomorphic.

Comment: @Vladimir  I am sorry. You are write. The map is certainly non holomorphic. In fact a true question is the following: Let $U=\{(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2\mid  zw \neq 0, z/w \notin \mathbb{R}\}$.Is there a holomorphic map $B: U\to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ such that $f(z,w)$ indicates to the bisector direction?

Comment: @AliTaghavi, take $B= w (z/w)^{1/2}$. This is in effect another way of saying $B=(zw)^{1/2}$, but perhaps writing it this way makes it clearer that it can be defined on your domain!

Comment: @SimonLRydinMyerson  Very interesting!thanks! This is morivation to have the following definition: We say a triangle $\Delta ADC$ is a holomorphic triangle if $B(A, D)=B(A,C)=B(C,D)$. This is written with a little abuse of notation but is meaningfull after translation of each vertex to the origin. Now a question: Which triangles are holomorphic?

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko  However "The intersection point of Bisectors" is not a holomorphic function of 3 vertex variable, but in my previous comment we search for a particular triangles whose "bisector intersection point" can be expressed, holomorphically. I would appreciate if you read my previous comment.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko  BTW do you have any idea on this question?Is there a pyramid analogy of the formula you mentioned in your comments above

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645549/the-intersection-point-of-bisector-of-a-pyramid

Comment: @AliTaghavi I think you should post that as a new question, making it clearer what you mean. It seems like you have a non-holomorphic function $F(A,C,D)$ of three complex variables $A$, $C$, $D$, and you want to find a set $S\subset \mathbb{C}^3$ on which it coincides with a holomorphic function $H(A,C,D)$. I speculate that you should think carefully about what properties you want $S$ to have. Does it have to be a complex manifold, for example?